# Tracking the products using Enhanced Ecommerce with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking, enhanced-ecommerce

I have implemented Google Analytics with  multiple trackers using this url : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers
Then have tried to implement enhanced ecommerce in it,But the product categories are not being tracked.In analytics panel , it is showing (not set). I don't know where i went wrong since am not a SEO Expert.

In header :

```
<script>
//Google Analytics
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-123', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-456', 'auto', 'abc');
  ga('create', 'UA-789', 'auto', 'xyz');

//Ecommerce tracking code
  ga("require", "ec", "ec.js");
//Ecommerce tracking code
</script>
```

In Product Listing,where all products of same category can be viewed

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  ga('ec:addImpression', {
  'id': '<?php echo $sku_idx; ?>',                   // Product details are provided in an impressionFieldObject.
  'name': '<?php echo $curr_product['disp_name'];?>',
  'category': '<?php echo check_product_brand($curr_product['category'],$curr_product['L2']).'/'.ucfirst($curr_product['category']);?>',
  'brand': '<?php echo $curr_product['style'];?>',
  'variant': '<?php echo  $attr_code?>',
  'list': 'Product Listing',
  //'position': 1                     // 'position' indicates the product position in the list.
  });
```

At the end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('abc.send', 'pageview');
ga('xyz.send', 'pageview');
```

Here is the console :

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
Loading resource for plugin: ec
Loading script: "https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js"
Running command: ga("create", "UA-123", "auto")
Creating new tracker: t0
Auto cookieDomain found: "mytest.com"
Running command: ga("create", "UA-456", "auto", "abc")
Creating new tracker: dieselitaly
Auto cookieDomain found: "mytest.com"
Running command: ga("create", "UA-789", "auto", "xyz")
Creating new tracker: syg
Auto cookieDomain found: "mytest.com"

Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "ec", Function)
Running command: ga("require", "ec", "ec.js")
Plugin "ec" intialized on tracker "t0".
Running command: ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "98263", name: "Ab - Jacket", category: "Apparel/Men/Jackets", brand: "123456", variant: "900", list: "Product Listing"})
Running command: ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "98263", name: "Ab - Jacket", category: "Apparel/Men/Jackets", brand: "123456", variant: "900", list: "Product Listing"})

Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("send", "pageview")

Sent beacon:
          v=1&_v=j44d&a=1234658035&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fmytest.com%2Fproduct%2Fmens%2Fjackets&ul=en-us&de=UTF-/...... some stuff here

_j1                                          (&jid)       
adSenseId                                    (&a)         1234658035
apiVersion                                   (&v)         1
clientId                                     (&cid)       819866210.1464779007
ec:impression list "1" name                  (&il1nm)     Product Listing
ec:impression list "1" product "1" brand     (&il1pi1br)  123456
ec:impression list "1" product "1" category  (&il1pi1ca)  Apparel/Men/Jackets
ec:impression list "1" product "1" id        (&il1pi1id)  98263
ec:impression list "1" product "1" name      (&il1pi1nm)  Ab - Jacket
ec:impression list "1" product "1" variant   (&il1pi1va)  900
encoding                                     (&de)        UTF-8
flashVersion                                 (&fl)        22.0 r0
hitType                                      (&t)         pageview
javaEnabled                                  (&je)        0
language                                     (&ul)        en-us
location                                     (&dl)        https://mytest.com/product/mens/jackets
screenColors                                 (&sd)        24-bit
screenResolution                             (&sr)        1366x768
title                                        (&dt)        Online Store: jeans, clothing, shoes, bags and watches
trackingId                                   (&tid)       UA-123
viewportSize                                 (&vp)        1349x291
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("abc.send", "pageview")

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j44d&a=1234658035&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2F  Some stuff here
_j1              (&jid) 
adSenseId        (&a)   1234658035
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 819866210.1464779007
.
.
.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("xyz.send", "pageview")

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j44d&a=1234658035&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fau Again some stuff

_j1              (&jid) 
adSenseId        (&a)   1234658035
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 819866210.1464779007
```

Sorry for pasting such a large console.
I console i can see all the impression data being sent to only one tracking account.Is other 2 tracking accounts getting the data ?

Comment: Shouldn't ecommerce product category be tracked with `category` and not `Product category`? But your console output looks like it's using `category`, so maybe you didn't paste in your exact code. Also which property are you wanting to track e-commerce into? You will need to run the same GA calls for those properties as well. Your e-commerce data looks like it's sent to the unnamed property, UA-123.

Comment: Ya sorry i had pasted wrong code.Have updated my code here. UA-123 is just a random id . I want to track in 3 different accounts. @nyuen

Answer (score 1):

When tracking enhanced ecommerce with multiple trackers, you need to include the tracker name and basically replicate all ecommerce calls for the specific tracker, for example:

```
ga('require', 'ec', 'ec.js'); // unnamed tracker
ga('abc.require', 'ec', 'ec.js'); // abc tracker
ga('xyz.require', 'ec', 'ec.js'); // xyz tracker

// ...

ga('ec:addImpression', .....); // unnamed tracker
ga('abc.ec:addImpression', ......); // abc tracker
ga('xyz.ec:addImpression', ......); // xyz tracker

// ...

ga('send', 'pageview'); // unnamed tracker
ga('abc.send', 'pageview'); // abc tracker
ga('xyz.send', 'pageview'); // xyz tracker
```

Comment: Thanks @nyuen . But still my product categories are not being tracked.Still its showing not set.

Comment: You'll need to wait at least 24 hours for the data to start showing up. Are you checking with GA Debugger in the meantime? Also, are you able to post your exact code? Also, you should be seeing the category for the unnamed tracker for property UA-123, right? Your console log shows that.

Comment: Yes i can see category in console.But have not idea y its not being tracked @nyuen

Comment: You can see category for which properties?

Comment: After modifying the script with your above solution i can see it for all the 3 properties

Answer (score 0):

you have parameter 'Product category', it is wrong
use name 'category'